# neo4j-rest-graphdb causes randomly a 502 bad gateway

Tags: java, json, rest, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Using SDN 3.1.2 and neo4j-rest-graphdb 2.0.1, I come across this exception while saving an entity (frequency 1/5):

```
2014-11-16T04:54:29.018090+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON '<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
2014-11-16T04:54:29.018095+00:00 app[web.1]: The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029618+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029620+00:00 app[web.1]: ! @6k83hj7gp - Internal server error, for (POST) [/api/meetings] ->
2014-11-16T04:54:29.018097+00:00 app[web.1]: </body></html>
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029622+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-16T04:54:29.018104+00:00 app[web.1]: '
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029615+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] application - 
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029624+00:00 app[web.1]: play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON '<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029625+00:00 app[web.1]: The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029627+00:00 app[web.1]: </body></html>
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029630+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029632+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029634+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029628+00:00 app[web.1]: ']]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029646+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57) ~[org.neo4j.neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029648+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62) ~[org.neo4j.neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029649+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114) ~[org.neo4j.neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029639+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029654+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.getRelationships(ExecutingRestAPI.java:553) ~[org.neo4j.neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029637+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029653+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.wrapRelationships(ExecutingRestAPI.java:383) ~[org.neo4j.neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029640+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON '<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029655+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029642+00:00 app[web.1]: The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029657+00:00 app[web.1]:  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@78338169; line: 1, column: 2]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029643+00:00 app[web.1]: </body></html>
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029658+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433) ~[org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:1.9.7]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029645+00:00 app[web.1]: '
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521) ~[org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:1.9.7]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029635+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029651+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.converter.RelationshipIterableConverter.convertFromRepresentation(RelationshipIterableConverter.java:45) ~[org.neo4j.neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.1.jar:na]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029666+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2770) ~[org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar:1.9.7]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029662+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442) ~[org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:1.9.7]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029663+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleUnexpectedValue(ReaderBasedParser.java:1198) ~[org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:1.9.7]
2014-11-16T04:54:29.029665+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:485) ~[org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:1.9.7]
```

Any idea?
**It happens since I upgraded to SDN 3.2.1 from 3.1.2.**

I'm pointing out that I can simply retry the saving, and the exception disappears...strange.
=> random

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem with your network setup? The HTML page that comes back sounds not like something that the Neo4j server would return?

Comment: Also your stacktrace doesn't show and neo4j or sdn classes?

Comment: `at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson` => **neo4j-rest-graphdb** might be the root cause, no? I didn't change my production code. Only upgrade the SDN library to 3.2.1 and Spring-Rest-GraphDb to 3.2.1 too. I've always used neo4j-graph-db 2.0.1 (no change to that).

Comment: Not sure, SDN pulls in the right dependency of java-rest-binding in, you shouldn't have to configure that yourself.

Comment: I'm not using Maven but SBT. I tried what you advised (removing the `rest-graph-db` dependency added manually) but I get that: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/RestGraphDatabase`. I guess that only the Maven version points out the dependency.

Comment: Can you trace the requests with ngrep or wireshark to see if there is something off?